# how to send updated results from servlet to jsp repeatedly

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to refresh marker on google map for live tracking for that, i want to repeatedly access database data from servlet to jsp page and again call to the servlet for current data. i tried with ajax,java timer,swing timer to updated result.but it doesn't work. please give me appropriate solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you post some of the code from your AJAX attempt?  That would provide a starting point. I'm not sure why you would use a 'swing timer' if this is a web application, but I'm not familiar with what exactly that is.

Comment: I am trying call servlet again for updated data to display cuurent marker on google maps using ajax.